# Syncing data logger iphone app start time with Labview start time

Tags: ios, iphone, logging, labview

I'm trying to sync a data logger accelerometer app with labview ECG equipment. I've previously solved this by trigger the ECG equipment with a 300Hz beep a test app. However now I need to use an app thats not my own to collect the data. Is there any way to know when the phone has started collecting accelerometer data so that an application can be made to run in the background and emit a noise when the collection starts?

Comment: Please re-frame and reword this question, an an (experienced) engineer I unfortunately have no idea what you are saying here :(.

Comment: Specificially #1) Are you asking a question about a new, never tried use case or do you have pre-existing code? #2)Explicitly detail your specified 'ECG Equipment Trigger Code', what it is made for, they why and how it works and #3) reword the question 'Is there any way -'. I have no idea what this means :(